# My form in django is not saving data to db model

Tags: python, django

The data of form is not being saved to the db checkout table. In this code I want to give to field `cart_information` the value from another model that is related to `user` with `session`.

The post request:

```
[06/Nov/2023 18:44:49] "POST /order/checkout-info/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

This is code:

models.py:

```
class Checkout(models.Model):
    cart_information = models.OneToOneField(Cart, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street_address_1 = models.TextField()
    street_address_2 = models.TextField(null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    order_notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    STATUS_LIST = (
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('processing', 'Processing'),
        ('cancel', 'Cancel'),
        ('delivered', 'Delivered')
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=STATUS_LIST, default=STATUS_LIST[0][0])
```

html:

```
<form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
        
            <div class="client-info">
                <div class="part1-of">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required />
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required />
                    <label for="company_name">Company Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="company_name" name="company_name" />
                    <label for="country">Country:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="country" name="country" required />
                    <label for="street_address_1">Street Address 1:</label>
                    <textarea id="street_address_1" name="street_address_1" required></textarea>
                    <label for="street_address_2">Street Address 2:</label>
                    <textarea id="street_address_2" name="street_address_2"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="part2-of">
                    <label for="city">City:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required />
                    <label for="state">State:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" required />
                    <label for="zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" required />
                    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required />
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
                    <label for="order_notes">Order Notes:</label>
                    <textarea id="order_notes" name="order_notes"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <button type="submit">GO to Payment</button>
        </form>
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from orders.models import Checkout


class CheckoutInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Make specific fields optional by setting required to False
        self.fields['company_name'].required = False
        self.fields['street_address_2'].required = False
        self.fields['status'].required = False
        self.fields['cart_information'].required = False
```

views.py:

```
class CheckoutInfo(View):
    template = 'orders/checkout_info.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template)

    def post(self, request):
        session_key = request.session.session_key
        session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)

        cart_information = get_object_or_404(Cart, session=session)
        form = CheckoutInfoForm(request.POST, instance=cart_information)

        if form.is_valid():
            print('def form isvalid')
            form.save()
            print('form.save()')
            return redirect('checkout_payment')
        else:
            print('else is true')
            for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                print(f"Field: {field}, Errors: {', '.join(errors)}")
            return render(request, self.template, {'form': form})
```

The form is valid and the redirect works but the data is not saved in the db.

Comment: Well your view does not *create* a `Cart` object, it *updates* one.